# GAE Restlet Sample "Missing required argument"

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to bring this sample to run http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/252-restlet.html but once I start it I get this message which I unfortunately do not know anything.

```
Missing required argument 'module[s]'
Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0
DevMode [-noserver] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s] 

where 
  -noserver        Prevents the embedded web server from running
  -port            Specifies the TCP port for the embedded web server (defaults to 8888)
  -whitelist       Allows the user to browse URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -blacklist       Prevents the user browsing URLs that match the specified regexes (comma or space separated)
  -logdir          Logs to a file in the given directory, as well as graphically
  -logLevel        The level of logging detail: ERROR, WARN, INFO, TRACE, DEBUG, SPAM, or ALL
  -gen             Debugging: causes normally-transient generated types to be saved in the specified directory
  -bindAddress     Specifies the bind address for the code server and web server (defaults to 127.0.0.1)
  -codeServerPort  Specifies the TCP port for the code server (defaults to 9997)
  -server          Specify a different embedded web server to run (must implement ServletContainerLauncher)
  -startupUrl      Automatically launches the specified URL
  -war             The directory into which deployable output files will be written (defaults to 'war')
  -deploy          The directory into which deployable but not servable output files will be written (defaults to 'WEB-INF/deploy' under the -war directory/jar, and may be the same as the -extra directory/jar)
  -extra           The directory into which extra files, not intended for deployment, will be written
  -workDir         The compiler's working directory for internal use (must be writeable; defaults to a system temp dir)
and 
  module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host
```

I use Eclipse 3.7, "Create a Web Application Projekt" with "GWT (3) 2.4" and "App Engine(4) 1.6.0"

What do I have to enter where, can someone help me?

Thanx Bobert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to start your GWT application in DevMode but the "Run configuration" in Eclipse is not correct. This is a an example of what the arguments in your "Run configuration" should look like :

> -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl index.html -logLevel INFO -war /home/koen/workspace/klawt/war -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 com.example.MyModuleEntryPoint

It is this last argument that is missing for you : com.example.MyModule. You must have a corresponding MyModule.gwt.xml in package com.example.

Comment: ok fine thanks! After i have add **firstSteps.FirstStepsApplication** in >Run Configurations > TAB "(x)= Arguments" > Program arguments:  .Its Start. But if i start in Browser http://localhost:8888/ i become the Error HTTP-Fehler 503 Service unavailable

Comment: I suggest you post a new question and include all info you can find, like console output from Restlet. This was actually a GWT related question. You are asking for help getting Restlet to work now.

Comment: I suggest http://blog.elitecoderz.net/missing-required-argument-modules-google-web-toolkit-jetty-does-not-start-in-eclipse-project-is-not-gwt-project/2010/04/

Comment: This helped me run Dev Mode on my newly-made GWTP project (GWTP on top of GWT).  I adapted the directions to Eclipse for making that project from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im1DGozNCsU&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score -2):

IIRC the versions need to be exactly correct.

Like I am using Restlet 2.1 and GAE 1.5.2.

Also note that Restlet 2.0 supports 1.4.2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I changed it but the result is the same.

Comment: dont see how this answers the question